# Sql error in localhost

Tags: php

```js
$query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (username, password, conirmpwd, gender) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password','$confirmpwd','$gender')";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    if($result){
        $msg="User Created Successfully";
    }else{
        $msg="Username is already taken";
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong with that error? 
Connected Successfully

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeinventor\register.php on line 12

Comment: Just check the manual before asking blindly:-`mysqli_query()` ask two parameter first one is connection object and second one is query. So provide your connection object here

Comment: ...and it seems as if the format of your insert string is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two things:-**

**1.Check mysqli_query() manual:- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php**

**`mysqli_query()` ask two parameter first one is connection object and second one is query. So provide your connection object here like below:-**

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);// here $con is database connection object(change with yours object)
```

**2.Also sequence used in `INSERT` query is not correct it should be:-**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, conirmpwd, gender) VALUES ('$username','$password','$confirmpwd','$gender')";
```

**Or if you have `email` column too in your table:-**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password,email,conirmpwd, gender) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$confirmpwd','$gender')";
```

Comment: you wrote incorrectly $con and i correct it $connection. It works... but one things is missing that what i fill it in the form is not fill up in database even though it is connect successfully

Comment: for the first one, its your responsibility to change things accordingly. second i don't know about your form fields and data so how can i suggest or say on that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k5zb8dsf/ see that link. I suppose input name should be different from table name or can type the same for both. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the connection that you made to your database. As, warning says, mysqli is a method which requires two parameters. So, you should pass two variable is mysqli() as :

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','your_db','db_username','db_pass');

$query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (username, password, conirmpwd, gender) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password','$confirmpwd','$gender')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($result){
        $msg="User Created Successfully";
    }else{
        $msg="Username is already taken";
    }
}
```

Comment: I already another file named connection.php with the first line of code. I create another for register.php to add query. There was an error trying to find out.

Comment: then include that file into this file and use the variable that you have used to connect the database like $con in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `mysqli` resource to `mysqli_query`. Like This:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbName);
$res = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'users' (username, password, conirmpwd, gender) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password','$confirmpwd','$gender')");
```

You would need to replace `$host`, `$username`, `$password`, `$dbName`, with your DB info!